# Can I check whether a lazy val has been evaluated in Scala?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

For instance, in a `toString` method, I would like to give info on whether a lazy val member of a class has been evaluated, and if so, print its value. Is this possible?

Comment: I fear an answer like “there's no API for that, but you can use Java reflection to test it manually somehow…”

Comment: There is. Every lazy *member* (different from local variables) has a backing field with a funky name that actually holds the value and I think another to determine "if evaluated". Not sure of the exact details/naming rules though. Sounds like an "interesting" requirement.

Comment: It's always problematic having to deal with a "lazy member"

Comment: More to the point... *why* do you need this?  The whole point of lazy vals is to abstract away from such implementation details.

Comment: @Kevin Wright: I'm toString'ing a class that contains lazy vals, and would like to avoid evaluating them in the toString if they haven't been evaluated yet.

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/LazyVals.scala#L182 is the code that does the work. So your comment to skirhiro4chawon's anwser is correct: you need to know the order of the lazy vals to correctly check the value of the bitmap.

Comment: It could always be done via a compiler-plugin, of course.

Comment: I keep meaning to ask this same question!  Glad I happened to come across it.  I wish there were a better built-in language mechanism for such checks, but it's interesting to see the solutions people come up with for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, you can´t. But you can help with that:

```
  class A {
    var isMemberSet = false
    lazy val member = { isMemberSet = true; 8 }
  }

  val a = new A
  a.isMemberSet // false
  a.member // 8
  a.isMemberSet // true
```

Of course, visibility and access modifier have to be adapted.

Comment: +1 Nice, but it duplicates the work the “runtime” generated by the compiler does anyway, and I was trying to access it directly.

Answer (score 9):

If you want direct access to the compiler generated field, please try the following code.

```
import java.lang.reflect._

class A {
  lazy val member = 42
  def isEvaluated = 
    (1 & getClass.getField("bitmap$0").get(this).asInstanceOf[Int]) == 1
}

val a = new A
println(a.isEvaluated) // => true
println(a.member)
println(a.isEvaluated) // => false
```

Comment: … and, funny enough, the magic constant to test for for a second lazy val is not 2 but 4 :-) Reorder the members and watch it break down… Who knows, change the class hierarchy, and it breaks because of a change in the number of lazy vals in the parents?

Comment: It is both delicious and repellent, and for it, you should either be lauded, or chided.

Answer (score 2):

I have also found it useful to check if the lazy value is in fact evaluated in some tricky situations.
And this is a generic class you could use:

```
class ExtraLazy[T](notYetEvaluatedValue: => T) {
  var isSet = false;
  lazy val value: T = {
    Logger("lazy value being evaluated");
    isSet = true;
    notYetEvaluatedValue;
  }
}
```